# How to set proxy for connecting of MQTT bridge?

Tags: proxy, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a mosquitto broker run on a linux behind my company proxy.
I have been configured a bridge to AWS same following: (mosquitto.conf)

```
connection bridge
address ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8089
remote_username admin
remote_password password
topic abc/raspi01 both 0
bridge_cafile /etc/pki/tls/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt
bridge_insecure false
```

But when I start mosquitto service with command:

```
service mosquitto restart
```

In log file, There are some errors:

```
1554356888: mosquitto version 1.5.5 starting
1554356888: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1554356888: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1554356888: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1554356888: Warning: Address family not supported by protocol
1554356888: Connecting bridge bridge (ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8089)
1554356888: Error creating bridge: Name or service not known.
1554356888: Warning: Unable to connect to bridge bridge.
1554356901: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1554356901: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1554356901: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as mqtt_fd05fada.b70918 (c1, k60).
1554356901: New client connected from 127.0.0.1 as mqtt_2a3a025d.6c941e (c1, k60).
1554356919: Connecting bridge bridge (ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8089)
1554356919: Error creating bridge: Name or service not known.
1554356950: Connecting bridge bridge (ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8089)
1554356950: Error creating bridge: Name or service not known.
```

I things the cause is my company proxy.
I have tried with settings in mosquitto.service, but it not resolve.

```
[Unit]
Description=Mosquitto MQTT v3.1/v3.1.1 Broker
Documentation=man:mosquitto.conf(5) man:mosquitto(8)
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=main
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:pass@proxyhost:8800"
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@proxyhost:8800"
Environment="NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,localhost"
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Can any body help me? Thank so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a HTTP proxy for MQTT bridge connection (or any native MQTT connection). MQTT is a totally different protocol.

Only MQTT over Websockets would work via a HTTP proxy, but you can not configure mosquitto to run a bridge with MQTT over Websockets.

Comment: Thanks for your support.
I have followed the instructions:

[https://akeil.de/posts/mqtt-bridge-with-mosquitto-and-nginx.html](https://akeil.de/posts/mqtt-bridge-with-mosquitto-and-nginx.html) 

But MQTT Broker in Lan network run behind my company proxy.
So, Can i deploy with this architecture?

Comment: No, and there is no need to nginx in this situation

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement that? Sorry if take your time. Thank you so much.

Comment: If your lan only allows outbound connections via a HTTP proxy, you can not

Comment: So, I can not create a MQTT bridge behind a proxy. Is it right?

Comment: That is what I've said several times now

Answer (score 1):

If one uses HTTP CONNECT before sending connect
in net_mosq.c

```
rc = connect(*sock, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen);
```

One can accomplish this.

HTTP CONNECT is protocol agnostic, it works on underlying TCP protocol.